# Functional style exception handling

Tags: python, functional-programming, error-handling

I've been told that in functional programming one is not supposed to throw and/or observe exceptions. Instead an erroneous calculation should be evaluated as a bottom value. In Python (or other languages that do not fully encourage functional programming) one can return `None`(or another alternative treated as the bottom value, though `None` doesn't strictly comply with the definition) whenever something goes wrong to "remain pure", but to do so one has to observe an error in the first place, i.e.

```
def fn(*args):
    try:
        ... do something
    except SomeException:
        return None
```

Does this violate purity? And if so, does it mean, that it is impossible to handle errors purely in Python?

**Update**

In his comment Eric Lippert reminded me of another way to treat exceptions in FP. Though I've never seen that done in Python in practice, I played with it back when I studied FP a year ago. Here any `optional`-decorated function returns`Optional` values, which can be empty, for normal outputs as well as for a specified list of exceptions (unspecified exceptions still can terminate the execution). `Carry` creates a delayed evaluation, where each step (delayed function call) either gets a nonempty `Optional` output from the previous step and simply passes it on, or otherwise evaluates itself passing a new `Optional`. In the end the final value is either normal or `Empty`. Here the `try/except` block is hidden behind a decorator, so the specified exceptions can be regarded as part of the return type signature.

```
class Empty:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Empty"


class Optional:
    def __init__(self, value=Empty):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return Empty if self.isempty else self._value

    @property
    def isempty(self):
        return isinstance(self._value, BaseException) or self._value is Empty

    def __bool__(self):
        raise TypeError("Optional has no boolean value")


def optional(*exception_types):
    def build_wrapper(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return Optional(func(*args, **kwargs))
            except exception_types as e:
                return Optional(e)
        wrapper.__isoptional__ = True
        return wrapper
    return build_wrapper


class Carry:
    """
    >>> from functools import partial
    >>> @optional(ArithmeticError)
    ... def rdiv(a, b):
    ...     return b // a
    >>> (Carry() >> (rdiv, 0) >> (rdiv, 0) >> partial(rdiv, 1))(1)
    1
    >>> (Carry() >> (rdiv, 0) >> (rdiv, 1))(1)
    1
    >>> (Carry() >> rdiv >> rdiv)(0, 1) is Empty
    True
    """
    def __init__(self, steps=None):
        self._steps = tuple(steps) if steps is not None else ()

    def _add_step(self, step):
        fn, *step_args = step if isinstance(step, Sequence) else (step, )
        return type(self)(steps=self._steps + ((fn, step_args), ))

    def __rshift__(self, step) -> "Carry":
        return self._add_step(step)

    def _evaluate(self, *args) -> Optional:
        def caller(carried: Optional, step):
            fn, step_args = step
            return fn(*(*step_args, *args)) if carried.isempty else carried
        return reduce(caller, self._steps, Optional())

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self._evaluate(*args).value
```

Comment: Your question has already been answered, so just a comment: do you understand *why* having your function throw an exception is frowned upon in functional programming? It's not an arbitrary whim :)

Comment: There is another alternative to returning a value indicating the error.  Remember, exception handling is *control flow* and we have functional mechanisms for reifying control flows.  You could emulate exception handling in functional languages by writing your method to take two functions: the *success continuation* and the *error continuation*.  The last thing your function does is call either the success continuation, passing the "result", or the error continuation, passing the "exception". The down side is that you have to write your program in this inside-out fashion.

Comment: @AndresF. I might be wrong, but isn't it because observing exceptions introduces state with the control flow?

Comment: No, what would be the state in this case? There are multiple problems, but here are a few: 1- there is one possible flow that isn't encoded in the type, i.e. you cannot know whether a function will throw an exception just by looking at its type (unless you only have checked exceptions, of course, but I don't know any language that *only* has them). You are effectively working "outside" the type system, 2- functional programmers strive to write "total" functions whenever possible, i.e. functions that return a value for every input (barring non-termination). Exceptions work against this.

Comment: 3- when you work with total functions, you can compose them with other functions and use them in higher order functions without worrying about error results "not encoded in the type", i.e. exceptions.

Comment: @EliKorvigo "Introduces state with the control flow" is not a phrase that makes sense to me.

Comment: @immibis Excuse me my bad wording (I'm not a native English speaker). I've meant, that observing a an exception and setting a variable's value based on the observation introduces state into the evaluation, doesn't it?

Comment: @EricLippert If I understand you right, I've already done that for the sake of practice, though I've never seen that in any real Python code. I've added the my old attempt on this to the question (a usage example is provided in the doctest).

Comment: @EliKorvigo Setting a variable introduces state, by definition, full stop. The entire purpose of variables is that they hold state. That has nothing to do with exceptions. Observing a function's return value and setting a variable's value based on the observation introduces state into the evaluation, doesn't it?

Comment: @immibis I've believed, that as long as you treat variables as constants, the evaluation is stateless, because the final output can be expressed as a long composition of functions (and intermediate return values stored in constants serve nothing but syntactic simplification and clarification).

Comment: @EliKorvigo This misunderstanding is arising because you and immibis are using two different definitions of "variables" (which is unfortunately overloaded in mathematics). To distinguish the two, we can call "variables" whose contents may change an *assignable* and "variables" whose value cannot change *identifiers*. Then there is no (or at least less) confusion.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Under that (also perfectly valid) philosophy, setting a variable based on whether an exception occurred is not introducing state as long as you don't set it more than once, is it? Just like setting a variable from a function's return value is not introducing state as long as you don't set it more than once. Note that in `try: ... exceptionOccurred=False except SomeError: exceptionOccurred=True` `exceptionOccurred` is never set more than once.

Comment: @immibis I agree with you in this context. What bothers me, though, is that if an unspecified exception will be raised and suppressed by an outer function, a variable may become undefined. Isn't it stateful?

Comment: @EliKorvigo Why is the outer function looking at the values of variables that haven't been defined?

Comment: @immibis Consider this case:
`
def fn1(*args):
    try:
        var = ...
    except Error1:
        var = ...
    except Error2:
        var = ...
    
    return var

def fn2(*args):
    try:
        var = fn1(...) ...
    except All_Errors as err:
        var = err
    return var
`
Would you say that calling `fn2` is stateful (I would only say that its return type is undefined)?

Comment: @EliKorvigo I would say that asking whether a function call is stateful makes no sense.

Comment: @immibis thank you for your time, you gave me some valuable information to digest.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all, let's clear up some misconceptions. There is no "bottom value". The bottom type is defined as a type that is a subtype of every other type in the language. From this, one can prove (in any interesting type system at least), that the bottom type *has no values* - it is *empty*. So there is no such thing as a bottom value.

Why is the bottom type useful? Well, knowing that it's empty let's us make some deductions on program behavior. For example, if we have the function:

```
def do_thing(a: int) -> Bottom: ...
```

we know that `do_thing` can never return, since it would have to return a value of type `Bottom`. Thus, there are only two possibilities:

1. `do_thing` does not halt
2. `do_thing` throws an exception (in languages with an exception mechanism)

Note that I created a type `Bottom` which does not actually exist in the Python language. `None` is a misnomer; it is actually the *unit value*, the only value of the *unit type*, which is called `NoneType` in Python (do `type(None)` to confirm for yourself).

Now, another misconception is that functional languages do not have exception. This isn't true either. SML for example has a very nice exception mechanism. However, exceptions are used much more sparingly in SML than in e.g. Python. As you've said, the *common* way to indicate some kind of failure in functional languages is by returning an `Option` type. For example, we would create a safe division function as follows:

```
def safe_div(num: int, den: int) -> Option[int]:
  return Some(num/den) if den != 0 else None
```

Unfortunately, since Python doesn't actually have sum types, this isn't a viable approach. You *could* return `None` as a poor-man's option type to signify failure, but this is really no better than returning `Null`. There is no type-safety.

So I would advise following the language's conventions in this case. Python uses exceptions idiomatically to handle control flow (which is bad design, IMO, but it's standard nonetheless), so unless you're only working with code you wrote yourself, I'd recommend following standard practice. Whether this is "pure" or not is irrelevant.

Comment: By "bottom value" I actually meant the "bottom type", that's why I wrote that `None` didn't comply with the definition. Anyway, thanks for correcting me. Don't you think that using exception only to stop execution entirely or to return an optional value is okay with Python's principles? I mean, why is it bad to restrain from using exception for complicated control?

Comment: @EliKorvigo That's what more or less what I said, right? Exceptions are idiomatic Python.

Comment: For example, I discourage my undergrad students to use `try/except/finally` like another alternative to `if/else`, i.e. `try: var = expession1; except ...: var = expression 2; except ...: var = expression 3...`, though it is a common thing to do in any imperative language (btw, I strongly discourage using `if/else` blocks for this as well). Do you mean, that I'm being unreasonable and should allow such patterns since "this is Python"?

Comment: @EliKorvigo I agree with you in general (btw, you're a professor?). `try... catch...` should *not* be used for control flow. For some reason, that's how the Python community decided to do things though. For example, the `safe_div` function I wrote above would usually be written `try: result = num / div: except ArithmeticError: result = None`. So if you're teaching them general software engineering principles, you should definitely discourage this. `if ... else...` is also a code smell, but that's too long to go into here.

Comment: I'm a PhD student. Carrying out seminars and preaching to the undergrads under my command are some of my responsibilities.

Comment: @EliKorvigo - Python uses baked-in exceptions for control flow - raising and catching StopIteration to exit for loops. Given a choice, I'd rather push down exception handling into implementation details, but where it's not possible, or preferable to avoid race conditions, I don't shy from using them. - See Raymond Hettinger's answer here that specifically addresses this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138232/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-try-except-else-in-python

Comment: @AaronHall I know that Python throws exceptions behind the scene all the time. Python does many impure things, even `map/filter/reduce` are stateful inside. But we still have the choice to avoid explicit state in our own programs by limiting it to IO processes and using primitives (such as `map/filter` or functions from different FP packages) to encapsulate state.

Comment: Minor note -- if you use Python's optional gradual type system (e.g. PEP 484), then you do get sum types via [Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union). There's also the [Optional](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) type. Of course, it's complying by whatever type annotations are written down is optional, but if you do typecheck your code using tools like mypy, it's possible to have nice things like sum types and [statically verifying that a value cannot be None](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#strict-optional).

Comment: @Michael0x2a I actually use MyPy. It does have a `Union` type, but it doesn't give sum types the proper behavior, because there is still no case construct in the language.

Comment: There is a "bottom value" (it's used in talking about the semantics of Haskell, for example), and it has little to do with the bottom type. So that isn't really a misconception of the OP, just talking about a different thing.

Comment: @Ben Ah, you're correct. But that wasn't what the OP was talking about (I think). One term comes from type theory, the other from denotational semantics, and this is definitely a question on the former.

Comment: Are you sure? "Instead an erroneous calculation should be evaluated as a bottom value" sounds a lot like the use of bottom values in denotational semantics, and not very like the bottom type.

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure. We'll have to ask the OP what he meant.

Answer (score 11):

Since there has been so much interest in purity over the last few days, why don't we examine what a pure function looks like.

A pure function:

- Is referentially-transparent; that is, for a given input, it will always produce the same output.
- Does not produce side-effects; it doesn't change the inputs, outputs, or anything else in its external environment.  It only produces a return value.

So ask yourself.  Does your function do anything but accept an input and return an output?

Comment: So, it doesn't matter, how ugly it is written inside as long as it behaves functionally?

Comment: Correct, if you're merely interested in purity.  There might, of course, be other things to consider.

Comment: To play the devils advocate, I'd argue that throwing an exception is just a form of output and functions that throw are pure. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Bergi I don't know that you're playing devil's advocate, since that's precisely what this answer implies :) The problem is that there are *other* considerations besides purity. If you allow unchecked exceptions (which by definition are not part of the function's signature) then the return type of every function effectively becomes `T + { Exception }` (where `T` is the explicitly declared return type), which is problematic. You cannot know whether a function will throw an exception without looking at its source code, which makes writing higher order functions problematic as well.

Comment: @AndresF. I was not sure what Robert wanted to imply, I could've argued for the other side as well (exceptions being not an ouput but rather non-termination). Of course you're right, the real side-effect of exceptions is that they change the type of *every* function in the project if only one function throws. Which makes reasoning for otherwise simple cases unnecessarily harder, and of course explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @Begri while throwing might be arguably pure, IMO using exceptions does more than just complicate the return type of each function. It damages the composability of functions. Consider the implementation of `map : (A->B)->List A ->List B` where `A->B` can error. If we allow f to throw an  exception `map f L`  will return something of type `Exception + List<B>`. If instead we allow it to return an `optional` style type `map f L` will instead return List<Optional<B>>`. This second option feels more functional to me.

Answer (score 10):

Haskell semantics uses a "bottom value" to analyse the meaning of Haskell code. It's not something you really use directly in programming Haskell, and returning `None` is not at all the same kind of thing.

The bottom value is the value ascribed by Haskell semantics to any computation that fails to evaluate to a value normally. One such way a Haskell computation can do that is actually by throwing an exception! So if you were trying to use this style in Python, you actually should just throw exceptions as normal.

Haskell semantics uses the bottom value because Haskell is lazy; you're able to manipulate "values" that are returned by computations that haven't actually run yet. You can pass them to functions, stick them in data structures, etc. Such an unevaluated computation might throw an exception or loop forever, but if we never actually need to examine the value then the computation will *never* run and encounter the error, and our overall program might manage to do something well-defined and finish. So without wanting to explain what Haskell code means by specifying the exact operational behaviour of the program at runtime, we instead declare such erroneous computations produce the bottom value, and explain what that value behaves; basically that any expression which needs to depend on any properties at all of the bottom value (other than it existing) will *also* result in the bottom value.

To remain "pure" all possible ways of generating the bottom value have to be treated as equivalent. That includes the "bottom value" that represents an infinite loop. Since there's no way to know that some infinite loops actually are infinite (they might finish if you just run them for a bit longer), you can't examine **any** property of a bottom value. You can't test whether something is bottom, can't compare it to anything else, can't convert it to a string, nothing. All you can do with one is put it places (function parameters, part of a data structure, etc) untouched and unexamined.

Python already has this kind of bottom; it's the "value" you get from an expression that throws an exception, or doesn't terminate. Because Python is strict rather than lazy, such "bottoms" can't be stored anywhere and potentially left unexamined. So there's no real need to use the concept of the bottom value to explain how computations that fail to return a value can still be treated as if they had a value. But there's also no reason you couldn't think this way about exceptions if you wanted.

*Throwing* exceptions is actually considered "pure". It's **catching** exceptions that breaks purity - precisely because it allows you to inspect something about certain bottom values, instead of treating them all interchangeably. In Haskell you can only catch exceptions in the `IO` that allows impure interfacing (so it usually happens at a fairly outer layer). Python doesn't enforce purity, but you can still decide for yourself which functions are part of your "outer impure layer" rather than pure functions, and only allow yourself to catch exceptions there.

Returning `None` instead is completely different. `None` is a non-bottom value; you can test if something is equal to it, and the caller of the function that returned `None` will continue to run, possibly using the `None` inappropriately.

So if you were thinking of throwing an exception and want to "return bottom" to emulate Haskell's approach you just do nothing at all. Let the exception propagate. That's exactly what Haskell programmers mean when they talk about a function returning a bottom value.

But that's *not* what functional programmers mean when they say to avoid exceptions. Functional programmers prefer "total functions". These always return a valid non-bottom value of their return type for **every** possible input. So any function that can throw an exception isn't a total function.

The reason we like total functions is that they are much easier to treat as "black boxes" when we combine and manipulate them. If I have a total function returning something of type A and a total function that accepts something of type A, then I can call the second on the output of the first, without knowing **anything** about the implementation of either; I know I'll get a valid result, no matter how the code of either function is updated in future (as long as their totality is maintained, and as long as they keep the same type signature). This separation of concerns can be an extremely powerful aid for refactoring.

It's also somewhat necessary for reliable higher order functions (functions that manipulate other functions). If I want to write code that receives a completely arbitrary function (with a known interface) as a parameter I *have* to treat it as a black box because I have no way of knowing which inputs might trigger an error. If I'm given a total function then *no* input will cause an error. Similarly the caller of my higher order function won't know exactly what arguments I use to call the function they pass me (unless they want to depend on my implementation details), so passing a total function means they don't have to worry about what I do with it.

So a functional programmer that advises you to avoid exceptions would prefer you instead return a value that encodes either the error or a valid value, and requires that to use it you are prepared to handle both possibilities. Things like `Either` types or `Maybe`/`Option` types are some of the simplest approaches to do this in more strongly typed languages (usually used with special syntax or higher order functions to help glue together things that need an `A` with things that produce a `Maybe<A>`).

A function that either returns `None` (if an error happened) or some value (if there was no error) is following *neither* of the above strategies.

In Python with duck typing the Either/Maybe style is not used very much, instead letting exceptions be thrown, with tests to validate that the code works rather than trusting functions to be total and automatically combinable based on their types. Python has no facility for enforcing that code uses things like Maybe types properly; even if you were using it as a matter of discipline you need tests to actually exercise your code to validate that. So the exception/bottom approach is probably more suited to pure functional programming in Python.

Comment: +1 Awesome answer! And very comprehensive as well.

Answer (score 6):

As long as there are no externally visible side effects and the return value depends exclusively on the inputs, then the function is pure, even if it does some rather impure things internally.

So it really depends on what exactly can cause exceptions to be thrown. If you're trying to open a file given a path, then no, it's not pure, because the file may or may not exist, which would cause the return value to vary for the same input.

On the other hand, if you're trying to parse an integer from a given string and throwing an exception if it fails, that could be pure, as long as no exceptions can bubble out of your function.

On a side note, functional languages tend to return the [*unit* type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) only if there is just a single possible error condition. If there are multiple possible errors, they tend to return an error type with information about the error.

Comment: You can't return bottom type.

Comment: @gardenhead You're right, I was thinking of the unit type. Fixed.

Comment: In the case of your first example, isn't the filesystem and what files exist within it simply one of the inputs to the function?

Comment: @Vaility In reality you probably have a handle or a path to the file. If function `f` is pure, you'd expect `f("/path/to/file")` to always return the same value. What happens if the actual file gets deleted or changed between two invocations to `f`?

Comment: @Vaility The function could be pure if instead of a handle to the file you passed it the actual content (i.e. the exact snapshot of bytes) of the file, in which case you can guarantee that if the same content goes in, the same output goes out. But accessing a file is not like that :)