# In the context of functional programming, what are 'total' functions and 'partial' functions?

Tags: functional-programming

I'm not finding via Google any explanation that my brain can grasp. Can someone explain this, and if possible, give an example of each using either pseudocode or C#?

The term 'total' function was introduced to me in the comments section of [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/334769/249648) question. The comment is:

> when you work with total functions, you can compose them with other functions and use them in higher order functions without worrying about error results "not encoded in the type", i.e. exceptions. – Andres F.

I'm intrigued by this comment.

Comment: I think this is not a real dupe. This question is about concepts on functional programming (see tag). The referred question is about algorithmic terminology.  The wording of the other question is very different and only remotely connected to this one. OP could not have recognized his interest therein.  It appears that one answer explains what a total function is, and another refers to total and partial functions without elaborating further.  But the fact of having some overlapping elements in the answer is not sufficient IMO for making it a dupe.

Comment: This has a community close on it, meaning the question author closed it as a duplicate. Yet there are four reopen votes? Madness!

Comment: @Snowman The question author is not the only one who gets to decide :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a reasonable definition from [the Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_functions):

A **total** function is a function that is defined for all possible values of its input. That is, it terminates and returns a value.

A **partial** function is a function that is not defined for all possible input values; in some cases instead of returning a value, it may never return at all (think infinite cycles), throw an exception (which usually states "this is undefined for this input value" or "unexpected input" or whatever) or simply crash the system.

A well-known example of a partial function is the integer division, `a divided by b`: it's not defined when `b` is zero!

Another example is `head`, the Haskell function that takes the first element of a list, which throws an error if the list is empty! Something like this:

```
head :: [a] -> a  // this is the signature
head (first : rest) = first
head _ = ... // This is an error! What is the first element of the empty list?
```

Partial functions like `head` unfortunately exist in Haskell for historical reasons. Note it can be made total like this:

```
headMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a
headMaybe (first : rest) = Just first
headMaybe _ = Nothing
```

Then you can safely call `head []` (`[]` is the empty list) and it will return `Nothing` instead of throwing.

Note that when looking at the original `head`, I cannot know just by looking at its definition that it may throw an error in some cases; I need to look at its implementation instead! That's bad. Compare this with `headOption`: just by looking at its type I know it sometimes returns a `Just x` and sometimes a `Nothing`, and I don't have to examine the implementation.

Comment: "Partial functions like head unfortunately exist in Haskell ": Why do you say "unfortunately"? What would be the alternative to `head` being partial?

Comment: @Giorgio The alternative would be something like the `headMaybe` function suggested near the end of the answer. Unlike `head`, where the user needs to assume/assert the list is not empty, `headMaybe` returns a `Maybe` type. When you want to extract the actual value from the maybe type, you need to explicitly state what should be done if it's `Nothing`. This means you can't use the value at the head of the list without specifying what to do if the list was empty.

Comment: I think partial functions have their place as a form of `assert`. In Rust, for example, the `Option` type(similar to Haskell's `Maybe`) has the `expect` method, which means - give me the value, and if it's empty this means the code is buggy and you should crash the program with this error message.

Comment: @IdanArye Haskell's `Maybe` has a similar partial function `fromJust :: Maybe a -> a`. I think they must be used with extreme care, if at all. The problem is that while you may know what you're doing at the exact place where you invoke this, it "taints" the enclosing function as well: now it too may throw an error. And so on and on. Now every caller must either trap the error (which cannot be done in pure code) or accept it has become partial itself.

Comment: That's why they should be treated as a form of `assert`. You don't ever want to catch and handle assertion errors - if an assertion error triggers it essentially means you have a bug in the code and the program's state is unstable. The only valid reasons to catch such errors is for logging/recording(write the error in a file, mail it to the developer, format it for HTTP response, display failure message in a test framework) or if you want to wrap it with a more meaningful error message. I see no merit in explicitly bubbling these errors up to `main`, where debuggers have no meaningful context.

Comment: @IdanArye: If you are not sure whether a list is empty, you can test this with `null` or destructure the list using pattern matching. While `headMaybe` is total, you have just moved the problem from testing if the list was empty to testing if the resulting `Maybe` value is empty. Bottomline: I find it convenient to use a partial function when I am sure that I am calling it on an element of its domain. For the same reason, `div` has type `Integral a => a -> a -> a` and not `Integral a => a -> a -> Maybe a`.

Comment: @Giorgio Like I said to Andres - having to explicitly bubble up the exception using monads all the way to the `main` function is too much of a hassle, and it's fine to throw an exception to indicate a bug in the code. The only problem is making it explicit - `fromJust` explicitly conveys that we have a reason to assume we have a `Just a` and not `Nothing`. `head` - not as much. So `head myList` is saying "give me the head of the list" while `fromJust(headMaybe myList)` is saying "give me the head of the list, I assume it has one, if no - it's a bug so it's OK to crash the program".

Comment: @Giorgio That you have to "test with `null`" is out of band information, so to speak, and that's bad. Merely by looking at `head`'s signature you cannot know this, therefore `head` isn't "safe". On the other hand, `headMaybe` is totally safe: there is no way you can make a mistake. Destructuring the list in this case isn't an option, because if you try to destructure `[]` as `x : _` it will fail and you lose type safety. This is why the Haskell community considers `head` and similar partial functions from the Prelude to be a mistake (that's the consensus by the way, not just my opinion!)

Comment: @Giorgio Another very real problem is that partial functions are harder to use in generic higher-order functions. I'm sure you'll see why :)

Comment: @AndresF.: I totally agree with `head` not being safe (and, BTW, I do not like partial functions and using exceptions). What I was pointing out is that using `headMaybe` you neither need to (1) check whether the list is empty, nor (2) catch a possible exception thrown by `head` or pattern matching. Bu now you have to either (1) check whether the `Maybe` value contains a value, or (2) catch an exception that is thrown by `fromJust` or by destructuring the `Maybe` value. So you have just moved the problem from lists to optional values. A

Comment: @Andres F: "Another very real problem is that partial functions are harder to use in generic higher-order functions. I'm sure you'll see why :)": Again, I was not arguing in favour of partial functions and using exceptions. In general, I am against using exceptions (they should only be used in **exceptional** cases). I was arguing that the `Maybe` solution suffers from the same problems as the list solution: you have to destructure the resulting `Maybe` value, or check that it contains a value, or be prepared to get an exception.

Comment: @Giorgio Maybe I wasn't clear, I wasn't advocating the use of `fromJust` precisely *because* it's a partial function! Using `Maybe` doesn't suffer from the problems we describe, and instead benefits from the full power of the type system. You cannot simply "use the value from `Maybe`" because the compiler won't let you. Contrast this with explicitly checking for the empty list: the compiler won't enforce this, and you're not taking advantage of the type system! After all, couldn't a Java or C programmer tell you "well, I can just check for the null reference, why do I need option types?" :)

Comment: @Giorgio To make it clearer: with `head` you don't "have to" check for anything. It's entirely up to you, which makes it dangerous. If you forget: crash! With `headMaybe` you absolutely *must* handle all cases (maybe by `map`'ing over the value, maybe by pattern matching against all possibilities), otherwise the code will not compile. The latter option is closer to the "if it compiles, it works" mantra we all strive for (though of course it's just an ideal :) )

Comment: @AndresF.: OK, I get your point: `head` is a standard function whereas `fromJust` isn't. I totally agree about having the compiler force you to handle all cases. What about `div` and `mod`, should they also have type `Integral a => a -> a -> Maybe a`?